# What are the main criteria while choosing between different ORMs

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dapper

In my new project I am very confused between which ORMs to use.
Our database queries are very complex.
We are mainly stuck between Dapper and EF 5.
I know dapper has performance benefit and i think EF has its maintenance and code generation benefit.

Believe me I search a lot to find the main criteria to make a choice , and a good comparison between this two but not find a satisfactory answer.

So which things i have to keep in mind while dealing with this.

Comment: If you are not sure, just try both. Create few repositories using Dapper and few EF. You will quickly find out which one works best for the project. My personal preference is to start with the simplest solution like Dapper and then progress into something heavier like EF when there is a need for it.

Comment: It also depends on the stability of the code base (stable: Dapper), the size of the code base (large: EF), required time to market (fast: EF), whether EF can even handle the level of complexity (no: Dapper), unit testability (required: EF), number and complexity of CRUD actions (high: EF).

Answer (score 0):

It's worth having a look at this [`Blog Post`](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/07/20/choosing-an-orm-strategy/), but ultimately, the criteria is set by you.  You need to decide whether

- rapid development
- performance
- Code-First
- DB First

or whatever else you're looking for and then prioritize the list based on, what's more important. Then use this list to compile your research.